# Update p:datatable row color conditionally after p:ajax

Tags: css, jsf, datatable, row

Using rowStyleClass won't work for me because I do not want to re-render the whole datatable. I have panelGroup's inside of my datatabe. I re-render the ones I need and it works just fine. But, I cannot figure out how I can change the background color of the cell row/cells that I have re-rendered. I can do things to the selectOneMenu or outputText styles but not the td/tr.

```
            <p:column styleClass="column5">
            <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupAN">
                <h:selectOneMenu id="accountNumber" value="#{var.accountNumber}" rendered="#{var.checkedBox}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="Select One" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.accountNumberList}" var="option" itemLabel="#{option.code}" itemValue="#{option.code}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="#{var.accountNumberDisabled}" rendered="#{!(var.checkedBox)}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
           </p:column>
```

EDIT (still not working)

```
      .yellowBG {
            background-color: #FBEC88 !important;
            background-image: none !important;
            color: #000000 !important;
        }
```

and

```
           <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupS" styleClass="#{var.checkedBox ? 'yellowBG' : 'column5'}">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4cAb.png

you can see a little bit of the yellow but i want it on the whole cell

EDIT 2:

figured it out with jquery.

```
    <p:ajax oncomplete="changeColor(#{rowIndex}, #{var.checkedBox})" />
```

and

```
 function changeColor(rowIndex, disabledCheck){
        if(disabledCheck){
            $('.ui-datatable-data tr').eq(rowIndex).children('td,th').css( "background-color", "#FDFEFE" );
        }
        else{
            $('.ui-datatable-data tr').eq(rowIndex).children('td,th').css( "background-color", "#FBEC88" );
        }
 }
```

if anyone ever needs it!

Comment: Just set an `styleClass` for the `h:panelGroup` which is conditionally changed?

Comment: it isn't working for me. i will edit my post to show you

Comment: Of course, in your provided pic you've the calendar component over the panel, so, even the panel is taking the colour it's not working for it. Anyway, you don't mention primefaces' calendar or whatever you're using in your question.

Comment: those are just 2 of 10 inputs/menus/calendars that are rendered on a row and happened to be the ones i took screenshot of. no need to mention the calendars i was just showing that styleClass wouldn't work and on my selectOneMenus you couldn't see any of the yellow so why would I screenshot them? But like I edited for a second time, I found a working solution using jquery. No need to be upset.